# Javascript Function Calculate on grid does not working when running on Chrome or Edge but working fine on IE11

Tags: javascript, asp.net

[image: debug value pic]
[image: screen pic]

******* why amount and total field does not automatic calculate correctly, it's still be old value and not change by calculation ***

```
function Calculate(txtQty, txtPrice, txtAmount, txtTotal) {
    var txtQtyObj = document.getElementById(txtQty).value != "" ? document.getElementById(txtQty).value : "0";
    var txtPriceObj = document.getElementById(txtPrice).value != "" ? document.getElementById(txtPrice).value : "0";
    var txtAmountObj = document.getElementById(txtAmount).value != "" ? document.getElementById(txtAmount).value : "0";
    var txtTotalHideObj = document.getElementById(txtTotal).value != "" ? document.getElementById(txtTotal).value : "0";

    var amount = txtAmountObj.replace(/,/g, '')
    var Total = txtTotalHideObj.replace(/,/g, '')

    if (txtPrice.value != '') {
        txtAmountObj = parseFloat(txtQtyObj) * parseFloat(txtPriceObj);
    } else {
        txtAmountObj = ''
    }

    if (parseFloat(Total) > 0) {
        var txtTotal1 = parseFloat(Total) - parseFloat(amount) + parseFloat(txtAmountObj);

        document.getElementById(txtTotal).innerHTML  = formatCurrency(txtTotal1);

    }
    else {
        var txtTotal1 = parseFloat(Total) + parseFloat(txtAmountObj);

        document.getElementById(txtTotal).innerHTML  = formatCurrency(txtTotal1);

    }
    document.getElementById(txtAmount).innerText = formatCurrency(txtAmountObj);
     
}
```

**** Amount box #1 ****

*** Amount box #2 ***

*** Total box **

Comment: I removed the `VB.Net` tag as I don't see any VB.Net related code or question. If I am wrong, please do add it back.

Comment: Got it. sorry for that.  Thanks.